# Separar cadena de texto JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Tengo un problema, necesito separar una cadena como la siguiente

***LOS MOCHIS CHOIX 6581 ALVARO OBREGON 4 3 35***

Y necesito que quede en arreglo de la siguiente manera
***[LOS MOCHIS CHOIX],[6581 ALVARO OBREGON],[4],[3],[35]***

Llevo horas pensando como hacer con JavaScript pero simplemente no encuentro la forma porque no hay forma de indicar dónde inicia y dónde termina

¿Alguna recomendación? Tiene que ser en JavaScript

Comment: puedes intentar separarlos con la condicion que tenga numero y cadena consecutivos, incluyendo que solo puede existir números o cadena.

Comment: Bienvenidx a Stack Overflow en español. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una forma de resolver el problema es identificando las partes de la cadena para luego separarlas:

```js
let cadena = "LOS MOCHIS CHOIX 6581 ALVARO OBREGON 4 3 35";

// primera parte
// cadena de caracteres en mayuscula con espacios
let regex1 = /[A-Z\s]+/
let primeraParte = cadena.match(regex1)[0].trim();

// segunda parte
// cadena de caracteres que inicia con un numero 
// seguida de caracteres en mayuscula con espacios
let regex2 = /\d+\s+[A-Z\s]+/
let segundaParte = cadena.match(regex2)[0].trim();

// tercera parte
// numeros separados por espacios
let regex3 = /\d+/g
let terceraParte = cadena.match(regex3);
// la expresión regular regex3 incluye todos los números
// por eso se quita el de la posición 0 que es el 6581
terceraParte = terceraParte.slice(1,terceraParte.length);

let result = [];

// insertar cada parte dentro de un arreglo
result.push(
  [primeraParte],
  [segundaParte]
);

// la tercera parte es un arreglo de números así
// que se inserta cada uno
terceraParte.forEach(e => {
  result.push([e]);
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvió mucho